# Error 403 Despite having a valid JSESSIONID (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

Hihi,

I'm very new to the whole OAuth2 and Spring security. I'm a student and would appreciate any help I can get on this topic.

I want to implement OAuth2 login for my project site. A lot like those websites that you log in once at the start and it persists throughout the use of the website (untill logout).

I'm using the name and email from the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` to retrieve the information of the current logged-on user to form a profile among other stuff.

All is well for all the `@GetMapping` paths. However when i try to post this form:

```
<form method="post" action="/api/adddrink">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <button type="submit" data-th-value="${cocktailDetails.idDrink}" 
         name="idDrink">Add to Profile</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

to the following path on my `@RestController`: `/api/adddrink`

I get an Error 403. I initially thought that it might be the redirect that my `@RestController` had. However, i soon found out that the code is not even being ran.

Checking the request headers, I see that the JSESSIONID is present. And the cookie is also present.

I've checked several tutorials to no avail. Something to note is that I do not have security config.

Things that I have done thus far to implement the OAuth2:

1. Added the following dependency: `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`
2. Set up the application.yml file to look like this:

```xml
spring:
  redis:
    database: 0
    host: ${redis.host}    
    port: ${redis.port}
    username: default
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            clientId: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
            clientSecret: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}
          google:
            clientId: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            clientSecret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

3. For all the paths that I need information from the logged in user, i've used this:

```java
@Controller
public class FrontEndController {
        @GetMapping(path = "/profile")
         public String currentUserName(
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
            String currentUserName = token.getPrincipal().getAttribute('name);
         return currentUserName;
}
```

And all is well. Till I post that above mentioned form :/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: first you should enable debug logging on spring boot, thats the basics of finding problems. Also you should use the web browser console to look for errors. This is most likely CORS, and we get about 2-3 questions a day about specifically CORS and there are 1000s of web pages explaining it. But without logs its impossible to be 100% sure. Learn to read logs it will help you a lot in the future

Comment: As @Toerktumlare mentions, enabling debug or trace logs will help. Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace` to your application.properties (or application.yml). You're most likely seeing a 403 due to [CSRF protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html) and will need to include a CSRF token in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Your "API" is an Oauth2 **resource-server** and your web-pages the **ckient** for this resource-server.

I don't see any security config for this resource-server. It should populate security context from `Authorization` header (not Jsessionid) either by decoding a JWT or introspection the bearer token on **authorization-server**.

You can start by splitting client and resource-server in different apps to better understand their respective config (you'll have to configure CORS on resource-server to allow requests from client socket)

Sample resource-server config here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples%2Ftutorials